# What is meant by "the superpotential is not renormalized"?

Tags: terminology, supersymmetry, renormalization

Reading about supersymmetry I often read the phrase

> *because of the [non-renormalization theorems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersymmetry_nonrenormalization_theorems) the superpotential is not renormalized.*

I would like someone to be more explicit on what is meant by this sentence. For concreteness sake, let's consider a theory with only a chiral superfield and with superpotential
$$W(\Phi)=M\Phi^2+\Phi^3$$
so, what are the consequences of the non-renormalization theorems for the different vertices of this theory?

Answer (score 3):

The non-renormalization theorems mean that there is only wave-function renormaliziation for parameters in the superpotential.

The important consequence is that there are no quadratic divergences for a mass in the superpotential - there are only logarithmic correction. The $\mu^2\phi^2$ operator is safe from large radiative corrections from, for example, the Planck scale.

Because $\mu^2$ ultimately sets the scale of EWSB (along with a few other soft-breaking parameters), this is very important. It's closely related to how supersymmetry solves the hierarchy problem.

Comment: I am a beginner at this so I would appreciate a lot if you were more explicit with what you mean by "wave-function renormalization" for the superpotential i wrote in the question. thanks!

Comment: It just means that only the fields are renormalized and not the couplings.